# Is this battery bulging/swollen?

Tags: hardware-failure, battery

I have had this Lenovo Chromebook for about 4 years now, and while taking it apart, I noticed that there was a small lump in the battery:

[image: Battery]

I am very worried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The battery is definitely swollen. You can see the paper covering has not wrinkled, but the battery itself has swollen.

It should be replaced immediately by a local service shop.

Swollen batteries are gone and no longer serviceable.

Comment: Not just gone. They're definitely dangerous and SHOULD NOT BE USED.